# Decremental connectivity on general graphs

Tags: graphs, connected

I'm looking for an efficient solution to the problem of tracking the number of connected components in a general graph under edge deletions.

General connectivity algorithms like that from
 [Holm, Lichtenberg and Thorup](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall03/cs528/handouts/Poly%20logarithmic.pdf) solve this problem and also feature edge insertion and connectivity queries, which I dont really need, but have an amortized poly-logarithmic update time and need log-linear space (which is most troublesome to me).

So I wonder if there is some more efficient approach (especially in terms of space complexity) considering the relaxations of the problem. I tried different approaches based on DFS and tremaux trees but eventually couldnt get some working solution...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you be more specific on "the relaxations of the problem"? What is relaxed to what? What is the usage pattern you are targeting, such as sparse graph or dense graph? Not that I know it will have much impact, but it is general helpful to make the question to be more specific.

Comment: You can use an algorithm for [decremental connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_connectivity#Decremental_connectivity). After each removal, you can check whether the two vertices are still connected, and update the count of connected components accordingly.